# Extjs hasOne association not loading preoperly

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a `Person` model which has an `Address` associated to it via 'hasOne'. Both models load data via REST proxy. If I load a person and try to get the address I can see a http request to the url of the addresses but without any kind of person id in it so my server sends an error.

Person:

```
Ext.define('AP.model.Person', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'int', persist : false },
        { name: 'name', type: 'string' }
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url : AP_ROOT_URL + 'persons/'
    },
    associations: [{
        type: 'hasOne', 
        model: 'AP.model.Addresses', 
        foreignKey: 'person_id',
        primaryKey: 'id',
        getterName: "getAddress"
    }]
});
```

Address:

```
Ext.define('AP.model.Address', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'person_id', type: 'int', persist : false },
        { name: 'address', type: 'string' }
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url : AP_ROOT_URL + 'addresses/'
    }
});
```

The following code:

```
person.getAddress(function(address){
    console.log(address);
});
```

creates a request to:
`http://localhost/addresses`

when it should create a request to:
`http://localhost/addresses/person_id (http://localhost/addresses/1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here is a `HasMany` relation, not `HasOne`. You won't get `HasOne` to work with these models because, as said in the docs: "the owner model is expected to have a foreign key which references the primary key of the associated model". In your case, the foreign key is in the associated model (which makes it a 1-n relationship).